# Port forwarding/mapping on AWS without a load balancer -- how did I do it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port-forwarding

I've got a real puzzle on my hands.

I've got a single Amazon EC2 instance, that I set up around 6 months ago. It's running an Apache HTTPD on ports 81 (unsecured) and 8000 (secured). It's also running a Tomcat on port 8443. But the outside world sees Tomcat (secured) on 443.

There's no load balancer involved (we have load balanced clusters; I know what that looks like).

The Tomcat and HTTPD servers are running independently of each other.

If I do a netstat on the EC2 instance, it shows that it's listening on 8443, but not 443. The active connector in the Tomcat's server.xml includes a "proxyPort" clause for 443.

If I do a curl from my desktop to the Tomcat server, on 443, I get something back.
If I do a curl from the EC2 instance to localhost, on 443, I get nothing; if I do so on 8443, I get a complaint about the cert being wrong for "localhost," so it's obviously connecting. So apparently, the mapping between 443 and 8443 is external to the instance.

And like a complete idiot, I left myself no notes whatsoever on what I did to make this thing work. Can anybody tell me what I did, and how I did it? Or at least tell me what to look for? I see a security group, but it doesn't say anything about remapping any ports.

Comment: You can't "curl to the Tomcat server on 443". Tomcat can't run on port 443 (without a lot of engineering), as its a privileged port, so whatever you are connecting to on 443, its not Tomcat. Can you re-produce the HTTP headers from the 443 connection?
curl -I https://<server>:443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it done with `iptables`?

Run `iptables-save` and look for a port mapping between 443 and 8443. Maybe `iptables-save | grep 443` for start.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Definitely not iptables. If I do an "iptables -L," I get only column headings. And if I do iptables-save, I get nothing at all.

Comment: @hbquikcomjamesl try "`iptables -t nat -L`"

Comment: iptables v1.4.18: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)

Comment: @hbquikcomjamesl obviously all the commands I mentioned are privileged, ie run "`sudo iptables -t nat -L`" or "`sudo iptables-save`"

Answer (score 0):

MLu said:

> obviously all the commands I mentioned are privileged,

AHA! Thanks!
After adopting root privileges, "iptables -L" still produces nothing but column headings, but iptables-save produces this:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Mon Jan  6 21:17:22 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [5018099:5766179544]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4555500:2863742410]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan  6 21:17:22 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Mon Jan  6 21:17:22 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [41828:2351495]
:INPUT ACCEPT [76356:4167904]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [254990:18418937]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [254990:18418937]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan  6 21:17:22 2020
```

I think I found something. Not quite sure what it is, though, or how I put it there.